# Vue 2 + TinyMCE Single Page Confusion

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, tinymce

I write quite a few single page vue 2 files but have never tried using a "component" before.  Can someone help spot the problem with my code?  The error I'm getting is "Editor is not defined".  Every example out there has you importing the vue module but I'm not using a builder so I thought just including the script(s) would work.  I have removed a lot of extraneous code to make it simpler to read (I hope).

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.X/dist/vue.js"></script>
...
<script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tinymce-vue/dist/tinymce-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="vue_app">
...
        <div v-show="showtable">
            ...
            <table class="tbdesign">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    ...
                    <th>Func</th>
                </tr>
                <tr v-for='row in filteredRows' :key="row.property_id">
                    <td :id="row.property_id">{{row.property_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
                    ...
                    <td><div v-on:click="editRow(row.property_id)" href="#">Edit</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section v-if="showeditor">
        <div >
          ...
          <form>
                <div>
                    
                        <div>
                            <label for="name">Name:</label> <input class="detail_update  id="name" type="text" v-model="editrow.name" />
                        </div>
            
                        ...
                    
                        <div class="form-group col">
                            Description:<br>
                             <editor
                               apiKey="no-api-key"
                              v-model="editrow.description"
                              :init="{
                                height: 500,
                                menubar: true,
                                plugins: [
                                  'advlist autolink lists link image charmap',
                                  'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
                                  'print preview anchor insertdatetime media',
                                  'paste code help wordcount table'
                                ],
                                toolbar:
                                  'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic | \
                                  alignleft aligncenter alignright | \
                                  bullist numlist outdent indent | help'
                              }"
                            >
                            </editor>
                        </div>
                    
                        <div class="form-group col">
                            <button v-on:click="submitData" type="button">Save</button> 
                        </div>
                   
                </div>
            </form>
       </div>
...
</div>
<script type="module">
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#vue_app',
        data() {
            return {
                rows: [],
                row: [],
                ...
                editrow: [],
                ...
                errors: []               
            }
        },
        components: {
           'editor': Editor 
        },
        mounted() {
            this.init();
        },
        computed: {
            ...
        },
        methods: {
            init() {
                this.loading = true;
                axios.get('/dap/api/?/functions/get_properties/')
                .then(response => {
                    this.rows = response.data;
                    console.log(response.data);
                    this.showtable = true;
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    this.errored = true;
                    alert(error);
                })
                .finally(() => this.loading = false)
            },
            
            ...
            checkData() {
                ...
            },
            submitData() {
                ...
            },
            editRow(rowID) {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.rows.length; i++) {
                    if (this.rows[i]['property_id'] == rowID) {
                        this.editrow = this.rows[i];
                        this.showeditor = true;
                        this.showtable = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Editor` is not actually defined anywhere in your code, and `<script type="module">` uses strict mode, requiring all referenced variables to be declared upfront. Since the `Editor` variable doesn't exist, the script immediately fails with the error you observed. However, it doesn't look like you actually need `<script type="module">` here, so you could just use a regular `<script>`.

> Every example out there has you importing the vue module but I'm not using a builder so I thought just including the script(s) would work.

The examples that import `.vue` files use a build system to automatically compile the imports with `vue-loader`. In this case you're using a pre-compiled script from CDN, so no loader is needed, but you do need to reference the correct symbol that the `tinymce-vue` script defines.

The `tinymce-vue` script sets its exports on `window.TinymceVue`. The pre-built `Editor.vue` component happens to be exported as the same name as the root export: `window.TinymceVue.TinymceVue`.

So you should locally register `tinymce-vue`'s `Editor` component as:

```html
<script>
new Vue({
  components: {
    editor: window.TinymceVue.TinymceVue,
  }
})
</script>
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/JjyYBVe?editors=1000)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I learned multiple things.  Can I ask how you figured out the editor reference was `window.TinymceVue.TinymceView`?  I see this in the script of tinymce-vue `exports.TinymceVue = t() :` and assume that's where you got part of it but I'm missing the logic as to why you would use `window.` and why `TinymceVue.TinymceVue`.  I know you tried to explain it but something there went over my head.

I've tried to use vue plugins many times and unless it has a specific example like I code, I often fail.  I think I'm not understanding something core about how javascript works.